# How change startup windows's services whitout login to the windows

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

i can't login to the windows because i do disable a services and my display after start windows is black, How i can re enable it with other windows?
services name is: "Unsigned Themes"

Answer (score 1):

Open MMC.exe on another PC connected in LAN. Add computer management snapin, and specify in next dialog box the remote computer name. The user on the second machine have to be the same with the same password and must be administrator. Or reboot the computer and start in safe mode.

Comment: Reboot fault windows in safe mode.